# Is it good practice to save separate server and ui files in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

There are at least two different ways of storing and deploying a Shiny app.

The first is to save `server.R` and a `ui.R` in `dir`files and run the app from the directory via `runApp(appDir = dir)`.

The second is to define both `server` and `ui` in a single `app.R` file and run it from there:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("child","child", icon("child"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I understand that there are human-level reasons why you might want to have `server` and `ui` in different files (eg. if the code is extensive), but most of the Shiny apps I come accross seem to follow the convention of using differente files. I realise that some people might also just be used to this since it was the original procedure. But, does is make any difference, technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tutorial video from RStudio's website (the makers of Shiny), it makes no difference technically.

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/how-to-start-with-shiny-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can select the structure that works best for you. When I develop a Shiny app I use a single app so as to navigate easily from ui to server